# monomer-dimer tiling of a Young diagram

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, tiling

As a modest start, I propose the below problem for a special set of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). Perhaps it is known.

Let $\lambda_n=(n,n-1,\dots,2,1)$ be the staircase partition and its corresponding [Young diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau) $Y_n$.

> **QUESTION.** In how many different ways (denote this by $a_n$) can one tile $Y_n$ using monomers ($1\times1$ squares) and dimers ($1\times2$ or $2\times1$ rectangles)? Is there a determinant (Pfaffian) formulation of this enumeration, in Kasteleyn's style?

Comment: The monomer-dimer problem for rectangles is open. I would expect staircases to be of comparable difficulty.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feed-back, there is a new variation of this problem at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327329/hooks-monomers-dimers-and-young-diagrams-for-a-bar

Comment: This is now http://www.findstat.org/St001380